# AvalonEdit TextDocument crash reading large files

Tags: sharpdevelop, avalonedit

I have an editor implemented using `AvalonEdit`, and when I open a new file I populate the `Document` with a new `TextDocument`, and populate that `TextDocument` with an `IEnumerable<char>`. That `IEnumerable` is just reading the file, char-by-char, from a stream.

We recently had it crash when opening a large file. Large meaning 600MB of plaintext. Don't ask, I think it's ridiculous, but it's necessary to be able to view files that big for our application. After a bunch of debugging, I found that the `TextDocument` constructor is crashing with an `OutOfMemoryException`, specicifically something where "Array dimensions exceeded supported range." Here's the relavent part of the stack trace:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Array dimensions exceeded supported range.
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Utils.Rope`1.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 input)
   at ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Utils.Rope`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 input)
   at ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Document.TextDocument..ctor(IEnumerable`1 initialText)
   ...
```

In my debugging I found that it happened consistently on the 134217728th character (2^27). That seems like an arbitrary limit, is there any reason that this would be a restriction? I'd expect the restriction of an array length to be `int.MaxValue`. It looks like it's something to do with the Rope creation, but I haven't been able to go into the `Rope<T>` source code yet.

Comment: In fact such issues are normal. If you want an easy way out, restrict the size of files opened in such controls, so that your end users cut their files to smaller ones. If you do want to fix this, you have to hack the source code of that control or see if the authors can help you out, https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/issues

Comment: 600 MB of ASCII text will be 1.2 GB in UTF-16. But Enumerable.ToArray() grows by doubling the array size each time, so it might be trying to go from a 1 GB array to a 2 GB array. .NET doesn't allow such large arrays unless you enable gcAllowVeryLargeObjects.

Comment: This was failing consistently at around 134MB of a 300MB file I was using for testing. It would seem like the max index should be max int, not 2^27.

Comment: I also tested the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects flag, and that did not change anything. It seems to be failing well before the large objects flag would be necessary.